# C++ Default constructors in union with variant member with non-trivial default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unions, default-constructor

I recently read a description of default constructors for unions:
[Default Constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

There is a following rule:

> Blockquote
>   Deleted implicitly-declared default constructor:
>   [...] T is a union with at least one variant member with non-trivial default constructor, and no variant member of T has a default member initializer.[...]

Then I decided to make an exercise and verify the rule.

```
struct Member {
 public:
  // Member() : mX(0) {}
  virtual int GetX() {
    return mX;
  }
  int mX;
};

union DefaultConstructor {
  int mA;
  Member mMember;
  int GetA();
};
```

With use of gcc v5.3.1 (I know it is pretty old) I receive expected error:

```
> ../src/DefaultConstrcutors.cpp: In function ‘void
> Test_DefaultConstructors()’: ../src/DefaultConstrcutors.cpp:26:22:
> error: use of deleted function
> ‘DefaultConstructor::DefaultConstructor()’    DefaultConstructor foo;
>                       ^ In file included from ../src/DefaultConstrcutors.cpp:19:0:
> ../src/DefaultConstructors.h:155:7: note:
> ‘DefaultConstructor::DefaultConstructor()’ is implicitly deleted
> because the default definition would be ill-formed:  union
> DefaultConstructor {
>        ^ ../src/DefaultConstructors.h:157:10: error: union member ‘DefaultConstructor::mMember’ with non-trivial ‘Member::Member()’   
> Member mMember;
>           ^
```

Ok, so according to rule, if I provide a default member initializer for a variant member, then it should compile. So I've changed union definition to:

```
union DefaultConstructor {
      int mA = 0;
      Member mMember;
      int GetA();
    };
```

And now it should compile, but I've received the same error.

Next step was to provide default initializer for a mMember instead of mA (only one union variant member may have default initializer).

```
union DefaultConstructor {
      int mA;
      Member mMember{};
      int GetA();
    };
```

Now it compiles.

The question is: why it didn't compile in second case, when mA had default initializer? According to mentioned rule it should be possible. What more similar rule is provided here: [Union declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial
>   default constructor, the default constructor of the union is deleted
>   by default unless a variant member of the union has a default member
>   initializer .

Anyone has an idea why doesn't it work?

Greetings,
Piotr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cppreference is generaly a nice information source, but here the compiler is right. Draft n3337 for C++11 contains in 9.5 Unions [class.union] a non normative but explicit note saying:

> If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default
>   constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be
>   user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union.

There is no mention that is will not be the case is one member has a default member initializer.

The same note still stands in draft n4296 for C++14 so I assume it should still be the same in the actual C++ standard. Notes are of course non normative, but their intent is to make more clear an interpretation of the standard, so I assume that the interpretation of cppreference is wrong because it does not respect that note, and that gcc interpretation is correct.

Comment: This is an editorial issue. Please check [Core Language Issue 2084](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2084) and [N4619](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4619.html) (the "Minor editorial fixes" part).